# KeystoneJS: How to create many versions of an image with different size, before or during upload to Cloudinary?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary, keystonejs

I am creating a model in keystone containing an Image, something like this:

```
MyModel.add({
  image: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage, autoCleanup: true }
})
```

I would like to have 3 versions with 3 differents size, like `thumbnail, normal, and large`. In RubyOnRails you can do it with the paperclip gem.

Does `Keystone/Cloudinary` have a similar tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is here:
[fieldtypes-cloudinaryimage](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-cloudinaryimage)
you can set "width" and "height".
or width undersocre methods:
scale(width, height, options)

Comment: Ok. Scale will make it.  But I am seeing a performance problem. It means each time I will need a specific size, some image processing will happens. It would have been better to process it once, and save it somewhere in cloudinary for future retrieval...